# Prove that the duration of a bond without a coupon is equal to its maturity.

Tags: finance

I am supposed to prove that the duration of a bond without a coupon is equal to its maturity.

I know it will have something to do with weighted average maturity periods, but I don't know how to formulate it.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Duration is in fact related to maturity weighted cash flows as you mention, but in the case of no coupon payments it is obtained in an easier way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a zero-coupon bond maturing in $T$ years -- with face value $F$ and (continuously compounded) yield $y$ -- the price is

$$P = F e^{-yT}$$

Duration is given by

$$D = \frac{-1}{P} \frac{\partial P}{\partial y} = - \frac{-TF e^{-yT}}{F e^{-yT}} = T$$

More details are given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bond_duration) regarding the distinction between modified and Macaulay duration and the formulaic conventions that apply when yield is compounded over semi-annual periods, etc.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: @Shelley: You're welcome.